# Flutter subscribe/query to one field in one file in cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

New to booth flutter and stackoverflow.
I am making the account verification functionally for my flutter app. My plan is to divided this functionally into two parts, part one shows an alertdialog when the screen is built, and part two checks if the "activated" field in firestore is true or false. **I have problem of making part two.**
This is what I write for part one

```
String uid = "fdv89gu3njgnhJGBh";
bool isActivated = false; 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      if (isActivated == false) {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: false,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return WillPopScope(
                onWillPop: () async {
                  return false;
                },
                child: AlertDialog(
                  title: Text("Activation pending"),
                  content: Text("Your account is waiting to be activate by admin"),
                  actions: [
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text("Refresh"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        // just bring reassurance to user
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
      }
    });
  }
```

For part two I plan to make a Future return type function, what it will do is to subscribe the boolean value that stored in firestore: /user/uid/activated, once the function gets a "true" from firestore, it will return it to part one and part one will close the alertdialog(which I haven't figure out how to do this).

I've already seen some solutions from the internet but most solutions involve StreamBuilder, but it seems that I don't need to build any widget for the stream in part two. Is it better to just make changes to what I write previously* or integrate both parts two one StreamBuilder function?

*What I wrote for get the data from one field among all files (and this works well):

```
  Future<bool> registeredCheck(String email) async {
    var userInfo = await _firestore.collection("user").get();
    for (var userInf in userInfo.docs) {
      if (userInf.data()["email"] == email) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to query the entire collection. Since you already know the uid, you can just get the document of the uid directly like this:

```
Future<bool> registeredCheck(String email) async {
   final userDoc = await _firestore.collection("user").doc(uid).get();
   return userDoc.data()['activated'] ?? false;
}
```

The reason why I am adding `?? false` is to return `false` instead of `null` when the activated value is null;